# Can I perform an android app testing which uses internet using the selenium webdriver?

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to test an andriod app which uses internet in its operation.If anybody aware about that then please let me know the way.
I am not talking about mobile version of any website which can be opened in android web browser,But an app which can run on android platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium Android WebDriver is for driving the Android web-browser, so no you can't use that to test a *native* Android application.

You're looking for something like Robotium http://code.google.com/p/robotium/

Comment: Yes something like this.Thanks.
But My question is,Can we do that using android driver provided by selenium hq.
For this Robotium I wish to ask Is this tool that much matured?

Comment: I can't say, my perception of mature may be significantly different to yours :) You'll have to look at their documentation and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Android Native Driver to test android based apps

Comment: Hasn't seen the comments of the user regarding native driver